# Can't animate a div using 'right' after setting css left?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The body part of my html is

```
<div class="scrollin" id="topscrollin" style="left:-300px;top:30px;"></div>
<div class="scrollin" id="bottomscrollin" style="right:-300px;top:120px;"></div>
```

the css part is

```
.scrollin{
  background: #3300FF;
  height:60px;
  width:300px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

the script part is

```
 $(".scrollin").animate({scrollin:27},{
       step:function(now){
        $("#topscrollin").css('left',now+'%');
        $("#bottomscrollin").css('right',now+'%');
       }
     })
```

and when they clicked on some other button

```
$("#topscrollin").animate({right:-300},1000);
               $("#bottomscrollin").animate({left:-300},1000);
```

the first animation seems to work. But the second animation doesn't seem to work for the topscrollin. When I searched I found out that it has something to do with initially setting position as left. 
I tried using the solution
http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/
which is given for the opposite situation. But it didn't work.
` Also if setting position as left is problem then why is not happening for the second case ?

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/RLAFq/4/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing to left & right 100%?
http://jsfiddle.net/PRLnm/

```
$("#topscrollin").animate({left:'100%'},1000);
$("#bottomscrollin").animate({right:'100%'},1000);
```